# How to make a POST with a GET as the promise

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-promise

right now I can select a Job that is already in the database and send it to a web api controller to be exported to a PDF. I am now needing to create a Job and send it to get converted at the same time. So I need some help on how the best way to do this is? Would I need to POST it, then have a function to call a Action that GETS the newest Job created in the db? Or could I somehow turn the form into a object that can be passed to the Api controller, before it makes a POST? I would think the latter would be easier but I the Action that sends the object to the api controller is a GET call? So here is how I am sending a job that is already in the db

```
<div class="inline-fields">
 <label>JobId:</label>
 <input ng-model="currentItem.JobId" type="text">
 <label>JobName:</label>
 <input ng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">
</div>

<input ng-click="EmailPdf(currentItem)" type="button" value="Email"/>
```

Controller

```
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
   var id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Api Controller

```
 public string Get(int? id)
    {
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
  JobDataAdapter adapter = new JobDataAdapter();
        Job job = new Job();
        job = adapter.GetJob(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        try
        {
```

This is how I create the Job

```
<div class="inline-fields">
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input ng-model="currentItem.JobNumber" type="text">
</div>
<div class="inline-fields">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerAddress" type="text">
</div>
<div class="inline-fields">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<input ng-click="EmailPdf()" type="button" value="Email" />

//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {
   var data = {
     JobNumber: $scope.currentItem.JobNumber,
     JobName: $scope.currentItem.JobName,
     CustomerAddress: $scope.currentItem.CustomerAddress,
  }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data); window.top.location.reload();
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can make a call to your pdf function from the success of your PostNewJob call.  Something like:

```
$http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
    console.log(data);
    // use the new object to call the Pdf api
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + data.id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
        window.top.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. but has the id been created yet? That is created server side on automatically, correct? Could I use another property such as the JobNumber?